# Check empty data set

Tags: sas

How can I check if the values are obtained by this condition?

```
data ad01(keep=str);
  length str $1024;
  set Address(where=(Type_="1"));
```

`///if resultat not null do something`

```
run;
```

Comment: What do you mean by your question?  I don't think you've made it clear what you're asking.  What does the comment mean there?  What is `resultat`?

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming you mean if there are any records that meet your WHERE condition you want to process them somehow.

You can do that with just:

```
data ad01(keep=str);
  length str $1024;
  set Address(where=(Type_="1"));
  *do something;
run;
```

If the dataset has no records with TYPE_=“1” the step will end when the SET statement executes and hits the (logical) end of file mark. If there are records that meet the condition, then any statements after the SET statement will be executed.

If by “do something” you mean execute additional steps (not just statements) this could become a macro language question. Where you would want a macro with an %IF statement, something like:

```
%if %anyobs(Address(where=(Type_=“1”))) %then %do;
  *data steps and PROC steps and whatever here;
%end;
```

For examples of function-style %anyobs macros see e.g. http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p095-26.pdf or https://www.devenezia.com/downloads/sas/macros/index.php?m=anyobs or http://www.datasavantconsulting.com/roland/Spectre/utilmacros/nlobs.sas

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin suggests this becomes a macro question. one way to do this is capturing count into macro variable.

```
 /* an example where count is zero*/
 proc sql noprint; 
select count(*) into :cnt from sashelp.class
 where name = 'unknown';
 %put &cnt;

/* Here datastep gets aborted if count = 0 */
data class;
if &cnt = 0 then abort;
set sashelp.class;
run;

 /* above query works when there is count gt 0 see the example below*/

 proc sql noprint; 
 select count(*) into :cnt from sashelp.class
 where trim(name) = 'Alfred';
 %put &cnt;

 data class;
 if &cnt = 0 then abort;
 set sashelp.class (where =(trim(name) = 'Alfred'));
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something when the SET statement return 0 observations you have to do it BEFORE the SET.  With 0 obs the SET returns and data step ends.  Consider this code where an observation is output when the SET returns 0 obs.

```
data class;
   if 0 then set sashelp.class;
   if _n_ eq 1 and eof then do;
      name = 'NODATA';
      output;
      end;
   set sashelp.class(where=(sex='X')) end=eof;
   run;
proc print; run;
```

[image]